# The Iris of my Eye

Tags: riddle

> Rarely you may think I'm seen
>   Often, though, can I be found
>   You can find me in the falls
>   Glowing well above the ground
>   Bending beauty in the sky
>   Interesting to the eye
>   Varied light waves arching high

What does this little poem describe?

<sub>This is not intended to be very difficult. I get bored in meetings and like to make up puzzles to keep awake. This little riddle is one of those.</sub>

Comment: Fairly simple, but it's a cute riddle!

Comment: Richard of York gave battle in vain, nice.

Comment: Yay! the first riddle I was able to get on this site without cheating through the spoilers

Comment: [Possible duplicate (and spoiler)](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/11664). (I'm joking of course)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> Rainbow

Because

> ROYGBIV (the first letters of each line) is the acronym for the colors of a rainbow red orange yellow green blue indigo violet
>
>  Also clues hint toward something rare and off the ground, but can be seen in many other circumstances. 
>
>  Particular clues that stand out are "bending beauty in the sky" "glowing well above the ground" and "varied light waves" which varied light waves grants the different colors.
>
>  Can be seen in water falls.
>
>  Iris is the goddess of the rainbow (credit to @f")

Comment: In Greek mythology, Iris is the goddess of the \[answer].

Comment: @f'' Colorful part of the eye! Nice! ... Wait...

Comment: Personally, I'd give this one the tick because despite being answered a little later, it included more detail earlier and notes the acrostic.

Comment: @feelinferrety Yeah, but what if it's not right?

Comment: @SendersReagent *if* it's right, Mr. Pedantic. :P  \*Edit to above: "Given the choice between this one and LearningPhase, personally..."

Comment: @feelinferrety How 'bout a tick to Z. Dailey and an upvote to LearningPhase for being quick on the draw?

Comment: @EngineerToast Ahh, so you're not a stickler like I. Well, I figured I'd try. =P I liked the puzzle and figured there was a pretty low chance that you were being as much a nit picker as I was. Of course, if this hadn't already been guessed, I wouldn't have even thought about how it could be anything else.

Answer (score 11):

Is it a

> Rainbow

1. > We usually/rarely  see rainbow in the rainy season
2. > Not sure
3. > It can be seen in the water falls
4. > It's can be seen above the ground
5. > With the rainbow the sky looks beautiful
6. > Once we see a rainbow we kind of like it, amuses our eyes especially kids.
7. > As it have different (varied) colors in it which can be see waving towards the sky

Comment: I downvoted since there was originally no explanation.

Answer (score 2):

Is it

> Aurora

Rarely you may think I'm seen

> Relatively rare phenomenon

Often, though, can I be found

> Yes, often auroras can be found in the north

You can find me in the falls

> When the nights grow longer, there is more time for auroras to dance

Glowing well above the ground

> They happen in the sky

Bending beauty in the sky

> They are very pretty

Interesting to the eye

> They change as you watch

Varied light waves arching high

> Not all the colors are the same

Comment: So the "ROYGBIV" is a coincidence?

Answer (score 1):

> The visible light spectrum

I think this is the actual answer because:

> As many have noticed, rainbow seems to fit, but technically a rainbow is only in the sky and due to rain and other water droplets in the atmosphere. So it would technically be the continuous visible light spectrum from red to violet.

Rarely you may think I'm see, often though can I be found

> Many people (children would make up a big portion of this) think that refracted light in the form of "ROYGBIV" is only seen in rainbows, but really, you can see it from refraction through many things. Sprinkler, prism, etc.

You can find me in the falls

> Can be seen in waterfalls due to refraction of white light by water droplets

Glowing well above the ground

> Well, refraction isn't actually due to the water glowing, but it gets the point across.

Bending beauty in the sky

> Rainbow is an example of the refraction spectrum of white light, in which case it's an arch in the sky.

Interesting to the eye

> Uses all the colors we can see.

Varied lightwaves arching high

> See "Bending beauty" above.

Lastly,

> ROYGBIV, as noted by Z. Dailey. Also, if you're actually an engineer (as your name suggests), there is a good chance you, like I, would get pedantic about minor discrepancies like this when it comes to physical phenomena.